# Can I jump from within PHP if{} to the else{}

Tags: php, if-statement

If I have code something like this

```
<?php
 if( X == Y ){
    find a record in the db
    some condition
 }
 else{
    do something
 }
```

is it possible to jump into the else statement based on `some condition`?

So, X *does* equal Y but then something about the db record found is a trigger that makes me want to run the `else{}` code.

I know I could duplicate the code inside the `if{}` or create a function.

This isn't some sort of mission-critical code, it is more a curiosity question.

Comment: Take a look here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.goto.php

Comment: You can't just run the `else` code, but there are plenty of ways to solve a problem like this. The solution will depend on the problem.

Comment: NOOOOOOOOOOOO..........................   Do not `goto`!

Comment: @AbraCadaver as someone who started with BASIC I know very well how to build spaghetti code :o)

Comment: @Steve:  Yes ZBasic and GW-Basic :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also do it without the else but with an extra if.

```
// Set a flag that tells us if we should run the code or not
$runIt = true;

if (X == Y) {
    $runIt = false;
    // Do cool stuff
    // If some condition:
    $runIt = true;
}

if ($runIt) {
   // Do your stuff...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP has `goto` instruction, but I'd suggest not to use it, but restructure code instead, probably to something like that:

```
function checkCondition() {
    // find record in db
    // some condition, return false if you want to go into else below
}

if ((x == y) && checkCondition()) {
    // action 1
} else {
    // do something
}
```